# Netlogo: move to a specific patch

Tags: netlogo, move, patch

I am gonna ask a simple question. I have workers and patches. Workers want to go to a specific patch, labeled by an id. I tried the following code, but it does not work. Can someone help me? Thanks

```
workers-own[selected-area]
patches-own [id]

ask workers [
move-to one-of patches with [id = selected-area]]
```

Comment: Hi Miki, can you also provide the part of the code where you initialise the variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example you have two important variables. `selected-area`, which is a turtles-variable, and `id`, which is a patch-variable.
Each agent (patch or turtle) can access its own variable, but not those of the others. The problem here, is that you ask the patches to compare `id` to `selected-area`, but patches don't have a variable called selected area so the program doesn't work.
The current structure of your program is:

1. Observer gives command to all agents (2)
2. Every agent gives a command to all patches (3)
3. Every patch tries to compare id to selected-area

A very nice tool for these sorts of situations is `myself`. `Myself` refers to the agent that asked you to do what you are currently doing, the one who is 1 level above you. In this case, it will allow the patch to check the turtle's variables.

```
ask workers [
move-to one-of patches with [ id = [ selected-area ] of myself ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks, myself was the missing part